# rsync - change/modify date not correctly set

Tags: networking, backup, rsync

Since Ubuntu 21.10 upgrade, we have a rsync error of file date set

In Ubuntu 21.10 : rsync 3.2.3-4ubuntu1 -> change and modified date are not copied during sync in most files

In Ubuntu 21.04 (and lower) : rsync 3.2.3-3ubuntu1 -> no problem detected (may be present but really discret)

With example on a file :

```
On u 21.10 for a file created at 12:45:07 :
Access: 2022-01-11 12:57:46.318656100 +0000
Modify: 2022-01-11 12:57:46.318656100 +0000
Change: 2022-01-11 12:57:46.318656100 +0000
Birth: 2022-01-11 12:57:46.318656100 +0000

On u 20.04 for a file created at 12:45:07 :
Access: 2022-01-11 12:55:46.318656100 +0000
Modify: 2022-01-11 12:45:07.420173200 +0000
Change: 2022-01-11 12:45:07.420173200 +0000
Birth: 2022-01-11 12:45:02.318656100 +0000
```

For context information : the error occur on local file and remote CIFS file

Comment: Sounds like my Question, has yound a solution? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/698273/strange-rsync-samba-btrfs-behavior-by-files-lesser-than-26mb